# Autodelete old files

Tags: cron, samba

I've many shares on my samba server with recycle bin module activated.

When deleting remote files from Windows I see `.Trash directory`.

I'd like to automatically remove older files, i.e. 30 days or older.

So I've added something like this to crontab:

```
00 01 * * * /usr/bin/find /share/share1/.Trash -atime +30 -print -type f -delete
```

However, if I've a file with last access 2 months ago and I delete it (samba will move that file to recycle bin), my script will delete that file at first run, because the last access was 2 months ago.

Comment: `-type f` should come first.

Answer (score 1):

from: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/vfs_recycle.8.html

```
recycle:touch_mtime = Yes
```

Specifies whether a file's last modified date should be updated when the file is moved to the repository.